# How to get particular images on particular days in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to display images on a website.
Let's imagine "image1" on mondays
"Image2" on tuesdays
"Image3" on wednesdays and so on  !
How do i achieve this in javascript? The images are placed in a function. How do take the images from there and show it on website?

Comment: Why do you want to do this with JavaScript? This decision should be made by the server. What programming language do you use on the server side?

Comment: I only have access to the front end!

Comment: Example: `if(new Date().toString().slice(0, 3) === 'Tue') document.querySelector('img').src = 'https://example.org/image2.jpg'`, just change `Tue` to something else, examples: `Mon`, `Wed`, `Thu`, etc.

Comment: There's no img src. The images are placed within a function called "images"

Comment: A function cannot contain an image. A function can only return the reference to an image.

Comment: @Vin can you explain what you mean by the images are in a function? Perhaps show a snippet of the function.

Answer (score 0):

If you really only have access to the frontend, you could use `switch`:

```js
const image = document.getElementById('dog-img');

switch (new Date().getDay()) {
  case 0: // Sunday
    image.src = 'dog1.png';
    break;
  case 1: // Monday
    image.src = 'dog2.png';
    break;
  case 2: // Tuesday
    image.src = 'dog3.png';
    break;
  case 3: // Wednesday
    image.src = 'dog4.png';
    break;
  case 4: // Thursday
    image.src = 'dog5.png';
    break;
  case 5: // Friday
    image.src = 'dog6.png';
    break;
  case 6: // Saturday
    image.src = 'dog7.png';
}
```

```html
<img id="dog-img" src="">
```

Comment: `image.src = \`dog${new Date().getDay()}.png\`;`  (optionally add 1 if you insist)

Comment: This would require that the names of the images have a unique structure. But a good addition, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could get the integer of the day of the week and map it to an array of images:

```js
const image = document.getElementById('image');

const imagesArray = [
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508185159346-bb1c5e93ebb4?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=55cf14db6ed80a0410e229368963e9d8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1900&q=80", // Sunday
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1495480393121-409eb65c7fbe?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=05ea43dbe96aba57d48b792c93752068&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1351&q=80", // Monday
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1501611724492-c09bebdba1ac?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=ebdb0480ffed49bd075fd85c54dd3317&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1491&q=80", // Tuesday
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1417106338293-88a3c25ea0be?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=d1565ecb73a2b38784db60c3b68ab3b8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80", // Wednesday
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500520198921-6d4704f98092?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=ac4bc726064d0be43ba92476ccae1a75&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1225&q=80", // Thursday
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504966981333-1ac8809be1ca?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=9a1325446cbf9b56f6ee549623a50696&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80", // Friday
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1437075130536-230e17c888b5?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=ff573beba18e5bf45eb0cccaa2c862b3&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80", // Saturday
];

const dayInteger = new Date().getDay();

image.src = imagesArray[dayInteger]
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%
 }
```

```html
<img id="image" src="">
```